# In Karate, how can I assert that an array does not contain a matching string?

Tags: karate

Let's say I'm writing a Karate test for a service whose response might look like tha following...

```
{
  "messages": [
    "The blurfl is wop",
    "The zog is ipfy",
    "The wuxhat is neet"
  ]
}
```

Is there some syntax for `match` to assert that none of those messages starts with "The baz "?  Or is there a more gereral way to test that in Karate?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "messages": [
    "The blurfl is wop",
    "The zog is ipfy",
    "The wuxhat is neet"
  ]
}
"""
* match each response.messages != '#regex ^The baz .+'
```

You could also do this:

```
* match each response.messages == "#? !_.startsWith('The baz ')"
```

And for completeness:

```
* def filtered = response.messages.filter(x => x.startsWith('The baz '))
* assert filtered.length == 0
```